# Возврат данных после отправки файла AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть некий код, который отправляет файл на скрипт и получает var_dump($_FILES) в ответе.

```
 $(':button').click(function(){
        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',  //Server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
                if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            //Ajax events
//            success: ,
            // Form data
            data: formData,
            //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });

    function progressHandlingFunction(e){
        if(e.lengthComputable){
            $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
        }
    }
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы данные которые возвращает скрипт upload.php отобразились в блоке с id='1'.

Как это осуществить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если upload.php возвращает /html, то можно попробовать заменить

```
//            success: ,
```

на

```
              success: function(msg){
                $("#1").html(msg);
              },
```

Comment: Благодарен то как) О msg совсем забыл) Балда я :D +1